# how to generate pdf using Wicked-pdf after the page is loaded?

Tags: wicked-pdf

is there a way to create pdf using wicked pdf after the page is loaded?

i want to create pdf after loaded, because i create the content for pdf after the page is loaded using javascript.

```
<div id="content">
    <!-- some content -->
</div>
```

I would like to create a pdf file using wicked pdf, but is there a way to create it after the page is loaded?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you can probably just create the pdf before it loads, since wkhtmltopdf can process and execute javascript. You may need to adjust the `:javascript_delay` setting if it isn't completely finishing running the JS.

Otherwise, you may want to package up the html in `#content#`, and send it as a param to a PDF-creating endpoint, with something like this:

```
$(function(){
  form = $('<form action="/pages/report.pdf"><input id="form_content" name="form_content"></form>');
  html_content = $('#content').html();
  $('#form_content').val(html_content);
  form.submit();
});
```

And an endpoint something like this:

```
format.pdf do
  @content = params[:form_content]
  render :pdf => 'report.pdf'
end
```

and a view that uses @content:

```
<%= @content %>
```

This endpoint probably should not do double duty with an html view, since that injected content could open you up to CSRF or XSS issues.